# excel export in client side

Tags: javascript, json, excel

In my js file I would like to use ExcelPlus 2.4 js for exporting json data to excel file. Checked here http://aymkdn.github.io/ExcelPlus/ . Please anyone help me to write ExcelPlus 2.4 js syntax for exporting data in json format from my ajax call success part to my excel.

```
function GetExcel() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../TestHandler.ashx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",        
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;

                ***var ep = new ExcelPlus();
                ep.createFile("Book1")
                  .write({ "content": data })**
                  .createSheet("Book2")
                  .write({ "cell": "A1", "content": "A1" })
                  .write({ "sheet": "Book1", "cell": "D1", "content": new Date() })
                  .saveAs("demo.xlsx");*


                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me to find a solution for exporting json data to excel (xls/xlsx) file. Please suggest me some working javascript/jquery plugin which has all browser support.

Comment: Please help me to find a javascript/jquery plugin for the above scenario.   support all browsers (ie8+, chrome, mozilla etc).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function export()
 {
   var tab_text = "";
   var textRange; var j = 0;
   tab = document.getElementById('your table id '); // id of table
   for (j = 0; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
      tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";       
    }
    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, ""); 
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); 
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))            // If Internet Explorer
   {
    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
      sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "print.xls");
   }
  else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
      sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    return (sa);
 }
```

Comment: I need to export json format data which is retrieved from a handler/code behind of my .net application. It will have nearly 5lakh+ rows, Expected excel file size is nearly 135MB. Can you suggest some javascript/jquery pluggin which has browser support?

Comment: means you want transfer json directly to excel or any size error you got when export

Answer (score 0):

You could use ExcellentExport.js library. It helps to create an XLS, XLSX or CSV file in the client side (browser) getting data from an HTML table or a JavaScript array.

https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/

Sample code:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <tr>
        <td>100</td> <td>200</td> <td>300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>400</td> <td>500</td> <td>600</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a download="somedata.xlsx" href="#" onclick="return ExcellentExport.convert({ anchor: this, filename: 'data_123.array', format: 'xlsx'},[{name: 'Sheet Name Here 1', from: {table: 'datatable'}}]);">Export to CSV</a>
```

*Note: I am the developer of ExcellentExport.js*

Comment: That library is easy to use.  I wish you could specify the column type.  Will be useful for Number.  I have columns with decimal numbers, but in the generated file, they are text.  Will be really fun to be able to add a class in a td, to tell (decimal number with comma as separator or dot.)